# How to pass data to controller using Fetch api in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I post data using fetch like this in my client js scripts

```
    fetch('/myarea/mycontroller/myaction', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify({ name: namevalue, address: addressvalue })
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.status !== 200) {
                console.log('fetch returned not ok' + response.status);
            }

            response.json().then(function (data) {
                console.log('fetch returned ok');
                console.log(data);
            });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(`error: ${err}`);
        });
    }, false);
```

Then on my controller

```
    [HttpPost]      
    public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction(string name, string address)
    {
        // Error, name and address is null here, shouldn't be!
        // more code here ...
    }
```

My controller action is being called correctly, and I am able to debug inside it, but no data being passed. What could be wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The controller action is expecting query parameters (`/myaction?name=myname&address=myaddress`). That's the default.
You're sending them in the body.

You can change the javascript to send them as query parameters. (see here: https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/256)

Or you can tell the controller action to take the values from the body:

```
[HttpPost]      
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction([FromBody] Person person)
{
    var myName = person.Name;
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set; }

    public string Address {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I introduced [FromBody] and PersonModel in the controller, but it is not hitting my breakpoint anymore at the controller. It is not calling my controller. Why is it so?

Comment: The PersonModel works with query string but not with [FromBody]

Comment: It now works! I just set the fetch api headers like this headers:  'Content-Type': 'application/json;'

Comment: Adding [FromBody] didn't work, event with Content-Type set to application/json

Comment: @KVM Me neither. Did you manage to get it to work?

Answer (score 8):

The [FromBody] attribute kicked in for me only after I defined the header that it is an "application/json" type:

```
fetch('api/Profile/Update', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ description: "Some text here" })
    });
```

And this is how the controller action looks like:

```
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody] ProfileUpdateModel profileUpdateModel)
    {
        //Do some stuff here...
        return  RedirectToAction("/", "HomeController");
    }
```

And the description property now receives the value from the request. Hope this gives final clarity to somebody tackling with the issue.

Comment: That URL you included in the fetch method: I assume Profile is the controller name and Update is the action method. I further assume its in the api folder. How do you configure this for it to know where the api folder is? Can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: @DeanP there is no api folder - just `[Route("api/[controller]")]` attribute which tells  ASP how to recognise the route

Answer (score 3):

Or if you had `<form>...</form>` you could use

```
fetch('/url', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    body: $('#editContactModal form').serialize() 
    // body like "id=1&clientid=3&name=me&phones=123&email=@mail.com"
})
```

without [FromBody] !!! (just with regular action method in controller)