# Vue fetch post data to controller asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js and I'm trying to make post request and send data { name: 'TestName' } to controller, but when I hit controller, instead name to be equal to "TestName" it's null.

**This is my Fetch: post request**

```
   `sendName() {
        let url = 'https://localhost:44362/Home/ReceiveName'
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ name: 'TestName' })
        }).then(function (response) {
            response
        }).catch(err => {
            err
        });
    }`
```

**And this is my action method ReceiveName in the HomeController**

```
 `[HttpPost]
    public string ReceiveName(string name)
    {
        *some code*
    }`
```

Here name must be "TestName", but it's NULL

I had tried answers from this question [How to pass data to controller using Fetch api in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44925223/how-to-pass-data-to-controller-using-fetch-api-in-asp-net-core) , to set `[FromBody]` in ReceiveName method like this   `public string ReceiveName( [FromBody] string name)`, but it doesn't worked for me. Then I tried to add headers to fetch body

```
`headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},`
```

But when i do this i get that error in browser

> Failed to load https://localhost:44362/Home/ReceiveName: Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status.

I think it's because CORS rules.

I'm running my backend on https://localhost:44362 and my frontend on http://localhost:8080/ so I had to edit my CORS rules in web.config like this

```
 `<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>`
```

**My question is** - 
How can I receive my data from Fetch:post to my action method?

*Is there a need to make query string?*

*But I don't want to send my string "TestName"  as `FormData` I know that if I send it like that I will receive it in my action method, but is this is a good way to send a string?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm ran into a similar issue and found a solution to my problem. I think you may need to define a model class with a `name` property, and then add [FromBody] to your action parameter.

Create a model class...

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Then use that model as your parameter type...

```
[HttpPost]
public string ReceiveName([FromBody]SomeModel model)
{
    // model.name should contain the value.
}
```

I'm not a fan of this solution, but it's the best I could find through my researching. Hope it helps you!

Comment: Spent a lot of time trying to figure this out.  Didn't realize I had to create a model class for it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately .NET MVC doesn't include the [FromBody] attribute (it is only available in Web API or .NET Core).  In order to access the information in the body of a post, you can use the [HttpRequestBase.InputStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequestbase.inputstream?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_HttpRequestBase_InputStream) property of [Controller.Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.request?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).

Here is an example (this code uses [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize the json object in the body of the request).

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReceiveName()
{
    System.IO.Stream request = Request.InputStream;
    request.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    string bodyData = new StreamReader(request).ReadToEnd();
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeType>(bodyData);

    //do something
    return Json(new { success = true});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
async function postData() {
    var data="abc";
    // Default options are marked with *
    const response = await fetch("https://localhost:44334/api/Blog/", {
      method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
      referrer: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *client
      body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    });
  }
```

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }
```

Set value into var data.   JSON.stringify(data). <3